# Solidity error :creation of buildTree errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: incorrect data length

Tags: solidity

I am trying to implement basic structure of Merkle tree , below is the code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract buildTree{
    bytes32[] private leaves;
    bytes32 private root;

    constructor(bytes32[] memory _leaves){
        uint n = _leaves.length;

        require(n>0 , "we cannot build a tree");
        require(n%2 ==0 , "number of leaves must be even");

        leaves = _leaves;
        root = buildRoot(_leaves);

    }

    function buildRoot(bytes32[] memory _elements) private  pure returns (bytes32) {
        uint n = _elements.length;
        if(n==1){
            return _elements[0];
        }

        bytes32[] memory  parents=new bytes32[](n/2);

        for(uint i=0;i<n/2;i++){
            bytes32 left = _elements[i*2];
            bytes32 right = _elements[i*2 +1];
            bytes32 parent = sha256(abi.encodePacked(left,right));
            parents[i] = parent;
        }

        return buildRoot(parents);
    }   
    function getRoot() public view returns(bytes32){
        return root;
    }

}
```

Now I m trying to pass the arguments during deploy (input=  ["0xabcdef", "0x123456", "0x789abc", "0xdef123"]) , its showing some errocreation of buildTree errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: incorrect data length (argument=null, value="0xabcdef", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is with the way you are passing the arguments.

You need to pass the arguments as an array of bytes32.

For example, the bytes32 of "0xabcdef" is "0x3078616263646566".

Here you can convert string to bytes32 https://www.devoven.com/string-to-bytes32